# Exit the program if an exception occurs

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to solve a problem on Hackerrank.
It expects me to write the error message "E1" when sth. is given incorrectly.

As you can see below; my result is actually true:

[image]

But it does not accept this because of the exception message:

[image]

The thing is, that **I should exit the program after getting this error**.
That's why I **rethrew the exception** in the catch block.

But it leads me to this problem.

```
    public void InsertEdge(char sth)
    {
        try
        {
            if (sth != sthElse)
                throw new Exception("E1");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to exit the program if an exception occurs, without throwing again an unhandled exception?

Comment: I know hackerrank pretty well, ive never seen it expect you to exit the program in any way! Have you tried just not rethrowing the exception

Comment: Rethrowing an exception is not exiting the program. It's crashing it.

Comment: Why bother with an exception here anyway? Instead of catch/throw, you could have output "E1" directly. Then maybe return a bool of false to indicate mismatch and bail out if this returns false in main method.

Comment: Your `catch (Exception e)` serves no purpose other than to `Console.WriteLine(e.Message);` which you could easily have done **inside** the `if` condition. `if (sth != sthElse) {  Console.WriteLine("Ooops!");  Environment.Exit(0); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only goal is to terminate the process you could call `Environment.Exit(-1)`.

Take a look here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=net-6.0

If you would like to pass an error code with more meaning that '-1' checkout this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes

Comment: If you want to terminate the process *due to an error*, the convention is to use a **non-zero** exit code.

Comment: Thanks @Heinzi. I fixed the answer an added more info.